Laravel 10 with reverb connection failed
I have laravel reverb working well in development, but can't get it to work in production. I always get the error in the console that websocket connection to 'my domain' failed
In my .env:
BROADCAST_DRIVER=reverb
REVERB_APP_ID=my-id
REVERB_APP_KEY=my-key
REVERB_APP_SECRET=my-secret
REVERB_HOST="my-servers-public-ip"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

in bootstrap.js:
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: 'my-key',
    wsHost: 'my-domain',
    wssPort: '8080',
    wsPort: '8080',
    forceTLS: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

Everything else in the config file is the defaults loaded from a fresh reverb install.
I'm using apache in ubuntu with php8.3-fpm proxied behind cloudflare and cloudflare ssl (so i don't have any ssl certs on the server itself). I've made sure that my iptables have an accept rule for port 8080 and if I use telnet with my IP and port 8080, I get a successful connection. I've enabled the ext-sockets in my php.ini file.
I've tried running a new port dynamically in the launch command:
php artisan reverb:start --port=8081
with no luck. When I run the --debug flag, I get nothing in the terminal except messages like "pruning inactive connections" and "pinging stale connections" or something along those lines. Nothing useful.
If anyone can help me, I will bless you to 7 generations.

What happens if you set your REVERB_SCHEME variable to https?

I recently had the same problem but with laravel 11 on cpanel (with Apache).


websocket connection to 'my domain' failed

Solution
Your echo.ts file should (it is advisable) to look like the following. or just ensure you use .env to prevent mix up
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

import Pusher from "pusher-js";
declare const window: { [x: string]: any } & Window &
    typeof globalThis & { Pusher: typeof Pusher; Echo: Echo };
window.Pusher = Pusher;

const _Echo = (window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "reverb",
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
}));
//Do things with _Echo

...



First ensure you had .env.production before running  npm run build incase it's a laravel + vite project like mine (never heard of one that isn't). in the .env.production edit the file and add or modify to something like below, this will ensure stuff like ws://localhost:8080/app are remapped well in production to something like ws://websockets.example.com/app
...

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="<replace with your websocket domain e.g websockets.example.com>"
VITE_REVERB_PORT=443
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=https
...




Next you have to ensure you ran  php artisan reverb   use option --debug incase you want reverb to show you some debug stuff :) also incase you need some queues you start them


Finally since reverb is running locally expose it to the internet with a proxy

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_wstunnel.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/app(.*)$ ws://localhost:8080/app$1 [P,L]

        ProxyPass /app ws://localhost:8080/app
        ProxyPassReverse /app ws://localhost:8080/app
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/app(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/app$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app
</IfModule>

just an advice: this is a simple version of putting reverb to cpanel. you might need to setup how you manage the processes including the reverb one, the queues and stuff you customized. Then build a script that runs all of that once instead of these tedious steps every time and restart/shutdown them if need be.

Laravel reverb work with laravel 11 it not work correctly with laravel version 10

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Reverb support Laravel 10.47+
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/reverb#installation
